# Why does futures::join of two executions of thread::sleep not run in parallel?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

Cannot seem to get the `futures:join` macro to execute in parallel using `tokio::main`.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.3"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

**main.rs**

```rust
use futures::join;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::thread;

async fn do_io() { thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(250)); }

async fn fetch() -> ((), ()) {
    join!(do_io(), do_io())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let s = Instant::now();
    fetch().await;
    let d = s.elapsed();
    println!("{:?}", d);
    Ok(())
}
```

**Expected Output**

~250ms

**Actual Output**

~500ms

Comment: `std::thread::sleep` will sleep synchronously, blocking the executor thread. You want to use [`tokio::time::sleep`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.2.0/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html) instead.

Comment: @apilat, so `futures::join` joins the futures onto the same thread and `thread::sleep` is a blocking call per future rather than async io... _nice_

Comment: @webish kinda? `futures::join` will basically pack the futures together but all of that will be passed as a single unit to the executor, and since your futures don't yield while sleeping (as they're a thread-level sleep) the executor will run the join() future, which will run the first do_io, which will suspend the executor itself for 250ms, then repeat for the second do_io. Tokio actually defaults to a multithreaded runtime, but that works at the [*task*](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.2.0/tokio/fn.spawn.html) granularity. And here you only have the `main` task.